# drawBackground of qgraphicsScene is never called

Tags: c++, qt

I have a class which overrides `drawBackground` of QGraphicsScene but my `drawBackground` implementation is never called.

```
class CtrlCutScene : public QGraphicsScene
{
  Q_OBJECT

public:
  CtrlCutScene(QObject *parent = 0);
  ~CtrlCutScene() {}

protected:
   //added override to make the compiler check that signatures match
   virtual void drawBackground(QPainter *painter, const QRectF &rect) override;
};
```

Any idea what I could be doing wrong?

Comment: Not much to go on here...  Have you also overridden `QGraphicsView::drawBackground()?

Comment: No i didn't. should i?

Comment: Definitely not! It would override the scene's `drawBackground(..)` - that's why I asked.

Comment: Excuse me for asking the obvious, but are you saying your overridden function is never called because you've put a breakpoint in the function, which is never being hit, or because you're not seeing what you think should be displayed?

Comment: i tried setting a breakpoint. btw. i found this bug report but it's about QGraphicsView: https://bugreports.qt-project.org/browse/QTBUG-2335

Comment: i just checked and `drawBackground`of QGraphicsView is beeing called.

Comment: i found the problem! The brush of the corresponding QGraphicsView has to be set to Qt::NoBrush.

Answer (score 1):

While the asker has found a solution of their case, I'm just posting here for the answer in my case because this is the first google hit for this issue.

In my case, I copy-pasted the function signature from a web page to ensure that I got it absolutely 100 correct and didn't typo.

And the function was never called.

The reason was that there was an invisible Unicode character U+FEFF right before the function name. And the QtCreator editor respects that character's zero width, so it was invisible to me even after pasting it in.

```
​void AnimScene::​drawBackground(QPainter * painter, const QRectF & rect) { // Evil
void AnimScene::drawBackground(QPainter * painter, const QRectF & rect) { // Works
```

Above is the line with and without that character, for comparison.

At least in the preview, Stackoverflow appears to publish a pasted U+FEFF ("zero-width non-breaking space") as U+200B ("zero-width space"). But, same visual effect.

If you are experiencing a problem that you think might be caused by this effect, one method to check is to close all files, then go to "Tools" menu -> "Options..." menu item -> "Text Editor" section -> "Behavior" tab -> "File Encodings" panel -> "Default Encoding" dropdown, and change it to something like US-ASCII. Click OK, and reopen your file.

See if any new characters in your function signature are visible as "unrecognized character" boxes. Don't save, since you might clobber extended characters elsewhere in your source that you don't want to clobber, but instead just close the file and change your settings back. Then reopen the file, and rewrite any lines which contained the boxes.